# div two column, right text vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

need help with  vertical alignment of `span`, a simple two column css for div with a `label` and `span`, align the text in `span` bottom, when label splits into 2 rows.

[image: screenshot span text vertical aligns top]

**CSS**

```css
div.form label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: .5em;
  display: block;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
 div.form label {
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
   text-align: right;
   margin-right: 0.5em;
   display: block
 }
```

```html
<div class="form" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 25px;  padding-left: 5px; ">
  <div>
    <label style="width: 200px;">Fiscal Period of 2018 End Date:</label> <span style="vertical-align: bottom; display:">08/31/1998</span> 
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
    <label style="width: 200px;">Type of Circular A-133 OMB Audit:</label> <span style="vertical-align: bottom; position: absolute;">S</span> 
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
    <label style="width: 200px;">Audit Period Covered:</label> <span>A</span> 
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
    <label style="width: 200px;">If Audit Period Other, Number of months:</label> <span tyle="vertical-align: bottom; ">4</span> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Looks like a table to me...is there a reason for not using one?

Comment: Also, extract the inline CSS to a separate stylesheet for easier debugging.

Comment: @Paulie_D I prefer using CSS than a table, is it  too difficult in CSS?

Comment: Well it's tabular data so a table would be more appropriate and semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply set `label`  as `inline-block` , and remove `float:left`

```css
.form label {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div>
    <label>Fiscal Period of 2018 End Date:</label> <span>08/31/1998</span> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Type of Circular A-133 OMB Audit:</label> <span>S</span> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Audit Period Covered:</label> <span>A</span> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>If Audit Period Other, Number of months:</label> <span>4</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline block  did not make any difference http://jsbin.com/koyuyoveho/edit?html,output

Comment: you didn't remove `float:left`,  I'm gonna add that to my answer, but you should pay attention to the FULL snippet

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Tables**

```css
.form div {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.form div > label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
.form div span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="form" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 25px;  padding-left: 5px; ">
  <div>
    <label>Fiscal Period of 2018 End Date:</label>
    <span>08/31/1998</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Type of Circular A-133 OMB Audit:</label>
    <span>S</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Audit Period Covered:</label>
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>If Audit Period Other, Number of months:</label>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

**Flexbox**

```css
.form div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.form div label {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 25px;  padding-left: 5px; ">
  <div>
    <label>Fiscal Period of 2018 End Date:</label>
    <span>08/31/1998</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Type of Circular A-133 OMB Audit:</label>
    <span>S</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Audit Period Covered:</label>
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>If Audit Period Other, Number of months:</label>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: may I ask why using CSS tables, when it is really, just  changing one line of code? (besides all of the unnecessary inline styles)

Comment: It's another option. Also the label & span will have the same height which `inline-block` won't do. In fact, flexbox might be a better option. But this really **should** be a table anyway.